# Is the sum of a convergent series from infinity to infinity always zero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.  Then $\Sigma_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ also converges for any $k>1$.  So my question is, in such a case, does the limit of $\Sigma_{n=k}^\infty a_n$ as $k$ goes to $\infty$ always equal $0$?

I think the answer is yes, because $\Sigma_{n=k}^\infty a_n=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\Sigma_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n$, and the right hand side goes to $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$ as $k$ goes to $\infty$.  But I just wanted to double check.

Comment: you are right. :)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: And, in fact, this is often a useful property for convergent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

Note that if         $$ \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty =S$$ then              $$\Sigma_{n=k}^\infty a_n=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\Sigma_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n =S-\Sigma_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n$$

Thus if $k\to \ $$\infty$ we get $$ \lim_{k\to \infty}\Sigma_{n=k}^\infty a_n =S-S=0$$